# iOS5 Simulator Notification Center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I've installed a new version of XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 beta SDK for Snow Leopard. I wanted to check the Notifications Center on iOS 5 simulator because I still  don't have the latest physical device (ipod, iphone > 3) to insall iOS 5. As I understand from the presentation, "android style" status bar will appear on top of the screen and we will see all notifications there. In case of local notifications if they fired up we will not see them as usual pop-up but they will appear in notification status bar.

After several tries I am still get a pop-up with local notification and I don't have any Notification bars as I supposed to have. So no notifications at all. I am running my application on the latest version of simulator with iOS 5.

Anyone is familiar with the issue?

Comment: NDA?  What an interesting concept.

Comment: Misplaced downvotes IMHO. It's under NDA, but the answer hardly breaks that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS 5 is still under the Non Disclosure Agreement, but I think I can tell You that not everything that is available on the actual software is also available in the simulator. Like Calendar.app for example