# how to view the notification center on the iOS simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

On the device swiping down from the top of screen brings the notification center, but how do I get the notification center on the simulator ?
I am on iOS 5

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989455/ios5-simulator-notification-center

Comment: I believe you'll need to test on the device.

Comment: @edc1591 That answer is useless now that iOS5 is not under NDA.

Comment: It's still valid. "I can tell You that not everything that is available on the actual software is also available in the simulator." The simulator doesn't have notification center.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok the answer seems to be that notification center is not available on the simulator

Comment: yes Dennis is right, this features is only available with device, You have to test on device.

Comment: Who said this is not available on the simulator. I agree with @Irshas Mansuri answer :)

Comment: Folks please look at the date on the question / response and the answer, as of Dec 2011, iOS5 it was not available, maybe in the latest simulator this support was added

Comment: for your kind information notification center is not for only push notifications, there is also local notification can be shown there..
and i didnt said that you can check push notification on simulator, its not possible to check in simulator but there is notification center is available in ios 6.0 simulator

Answer (score 13):

its available in ios 6.0

just drag your mouse pointer down from status bar... :)